# InnerHTML change works in firefox but not IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

So I have an options element and I"m trying to change the values based on a radio button. 
I wasn't able to clear/add the options element in an easy way so I want to just change the inner html. It works in Firefox ,but not in IE.

my select option

```
 <select name="TOR" id="TOR">
  <option value="MVR Only">MVR Only</option>
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option> 
  <option value="Employee + MVR">Employee + MVR</option>
  <option value="Faculty">Faculty</option>
  <option value="Faculty + MVR">Faculty + MVR</option>  
  <option value="Students">Students</option>
  <option value="Students + MVR">Students + MVR</option>
  <option value="Volunteers">Volunteers</option>
  <option value="Volunteers + MVR">Volunteers + MVR</option>
  <option value="International Employee">International Employee</option>  
  <option value="International Employee + MVR">International Employee + MVR</option>
  <option value="International Faculty">International Faculty</option>
  <option value="International Faculty + MVR">International Faculty + MVR)</option>
  <option value="International Students">International Students)</option>
  <option value="International Students + MVR">International Students + MVR)</option>
  <option value="International Volunteers">International Volunteers)</option>
  <option value="International Volunteers + MVR">International Volunteers + MVR)</option>
  </select>
```

JavaScript to change the options

```
 <script>
 function RadioChange(){
    var x = document.getElementById("TOR");
    x.innerHTML = " ";
if(document.getElementsByName("FTE")[0].checked == true){   
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="MVR Only(FTE)">MVR Only(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Employee(FTE)">Employee(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Employee + MVR(FTE)">Employee + MVR(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Faculty(FTE)">Faculty(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Faculty + MVR(FTE)">Faculty + MVR(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Employee(FTE)">International Employee(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Employee + MVR(FTE)">International Employee + MVR(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Faculty(FTE)">International Faculty(FTE)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Faculty + MVR(FTE)">International Faculty + MVR(FTE)</option>';
}   

if(document.getElementsByName("FTE")[1].checked==true){ 
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="MVR Only">MVR Only</option>'; 
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Employee">Employee</option>'; 
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Employee + MVR">Employee + MVR</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Faculty">Faculty</option>';  
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Faculty + MVR">Faculty + MVR</option>';  
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Students">Students</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Students + MVR">Students + MVR</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Volunteers">Volunteers</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="Volunteers + MVR">Volunteers + MVR</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Employee">International Employee</option>';  
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Employee + MVR">International Employee + MVR</option>';  
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Faculty">International Faculty</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Faculty + MVR">International Faculty + MVR)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Students">International Students)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Students + MVR">International Students + MVR)</option>'; 
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Volunteers">International Volunteers)</option>';
    x.innerHTML +='<option value="International Volunteers + MVR">International Volunteers + MVR)</option>';
    }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Plenty of other dupes if you search.

Comment: See my answer. Should fix your problem

Answer (score 3):

Use the proper DOM functions and you shouldn't run into problems.  I'm on my phone and will edit this later but basically...

```
      Var x = document.getElementById("TOR");
      Var y = document.createElement("option");
      // do stuff with y, like add attributes/value
      x.appendChild(y);
```